# Virus shuts down Avast

Tags: virus, virus-removal, avast

I have recently been attacked badly by a virus. Unfortunately I did not had an AntiVirus at that moment(I understand that it was a very practice by me.) Now after reinstalling Windows I have tried to install Avast but whenever I install Avast It shows up a blue screen prompting the error message of memory dump and restarts. I have tried to install it in Safe Mode too but the problem remains the same. I would be very thankful if someone could give me a good idea how to deal with such a condition. Thanks.

Comment: Did you reformat the partition/hard drive before reinstalling Windows? If not it could be that the virus isn't completely removed.

Comment: I agree with ChrisF, you could see if it is a [root kit](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280684) or [boot kit](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/solutions?qid=208280748) that is still hooked. TDSSKiller which is linked above will detect both. Run it on this machine.

Comment: What's the blue screen Stop error code?

Comment: @ChrisF: No, as all my important data was there so I could not format it.

Comment: @opsin: I tried it, but when I run it, the same problem happens as happened by Avast.

Comment: @techie007: Its was a big error code, would it help if I note it down?

Comment: @Akito - We cannot help you fix the problem that causes the computer to restart without it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to take the drive out of the machine, put it into an external caddy then use a second machine to create a backup of your data before reformatting the drive.

Actually you don't need a second machine. Buy a new drive for your machine. Swap the out the old drive and install Windows on the new one. Put the old drive in a caddy and use that as an external hard drive/backup drive for your data.

It won't reinfect your new drive as it's not a boot drive. You can also delete the remains of the Windows folder and Program Files folder just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have two drives but did not think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Avast is almost helpless when you have already got serious virus.

Leading anti-virus vendors have special solutions in live-cd or simple .exe format to cure system without anti-virus software installation.

For example, [Kaspersky Rescue Disc](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk?level=2)

or [CureIT from Dr.Web](http://www.freedrweb.com/cureit/) - no installation needed, just one file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but when I ran it, it gave me the same problem as by Avast.

Comment: While I agree Avast is one of the least effective programs on the market, to be fair to Avast, at this stage of an infection nearly ALL security problems would have a problem.  One exception AT THIS TIME would be Malwarebytes because of a new feature that prevent the blocking of their process.